# Occasional overfull \vbox warnings

Tags: boxes, multicol, warnings

Depending on the value of `\aeheight` I may or may not get `Overfull \vbox` errors.  I don't understand why.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.25in}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newlength{\aeheight}
\setlength{\aeheight}{6in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t][\aeheight]{10in}
\begin{multicols}{4}
  \lipsum[1-2]
  \rule{4pt}{\aeheight}
\end{multicols}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

However, if I set `\aeheight` to `3in`, then I don't get such errors.

Can anyone explain why different values are generating the warnings?

Comment: The rule is too big when `multicol` does the balancing.

Comment: @egreg But then why doesn't it complain when the rule is `3in`?

Comment: Probably because it finds a good height before starting the trial typesetting. You can see the computations by issuing `\setcounter{tracingmulticols}{2}`

Comment: This is nearly equal: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38496/how-to-avoid-underfull-vbox-in-combination-with-vsplit